# Making two independent service calls from Monix Observable

Tags: scala, reactive-programming, monix

### Versions:

Scala Version: `2.12.9`, monix/eval: `2.3.2`, monix/reactive: `2.3.2`

### Backdrop:

I have two services `serviceA` and `serviceB` to call from a Monix observable. The program is as follows.

```scala
import monix.reactive.subjects.PublishToOneSubject
import monix.eval.Task
import monix.execution.Scheduler
import monix.execution.Ack.Continue
import java.time.LocalDateTime
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter

val formatter: DateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss.SSSS");
def timestamp = formatter.format(LocalDateTime.now)
def log = s"[$timestamp] [${Thread.currentThread.getName}]"

println(s"$log Program Starts.")

private def serviceA(num: Int) = Task {
  println(s"$log A: ${num}")
  Thread.sleep(1000)
  num * 10
}

private def serviceB(num: Int) = Task {
  println(s"$log B: ${num}")
  Thread.sleep(5 * 1000)
  num * 0.5
}

private val aCtx = Scheduler.fixedPool("aCtx", 2)
private val bCtx = Scheduler.fixedPool("bCtx", 2)

val stream: PublishToOneSubject[Int] = PublishToOneSubject[Int]

stream
  .doOnSubscribe( () => println(s"$log Stream is ready!"))
  .doOnNext {
    v => println(s"$log Event: ${v}")
  }
  .mapAsync(parallelism=3) {
    v =>
      serviceA(v)
        .zip(serviceB(v).executeOn(bCtx))
        .map(_._1)
  }
  .subscribe(
    nextFn = { v =>
        println(s"$log Result: ${v}")
        Continue
    }
  )(aCtx)

(1 to 10).foreach {
  i => stream.onNext(i)
}


Thread.sleep(30 * 1000)
println(s"$log Program Ends.")
```

### Question:

How to ensure that any latency in calling `serviceB` doesn't impact the stream and it continues to process events with `serviceA` and return results?

Though I need to call `serviceB`, I am only interested in result of `serviceA`. I don't want any slowness in calling `serviceB` to impact `ServiceA`. Using `zip` delays the result if there is a latency in `serviceB` call.

Comment: So essentially you want to trigger the second task as a background process. In modern **cats-effect** that could be done using a `Supervisor`, no idea what is the **Monix** equivalent.

Comment: Yes. Kind of. Also need to ensure that when serviceB is slower, it can cause the all threads in ctxB get occupied which can eventually start throwing ThreadRejectedException. This should be handled gracefully and shouldn't impact the stream.